# SharePoint 2007 Web parts view size

Tags: web-part, formatting

Can the view of web parts be zoomed in or out?  I have a named Excel Chart displayed in an Excel Web Access web part.  The chart appears very large in the web part.  Is there any way to adjust the size of the chart in the webpart?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem; looked everywhere; a million complaints but no solution.

I ended up changing the font size and then modifying the dimensions of the rows and columns. If somebody tries to read that on a chromebook/netbook now, they will need binoculars.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't apply it, but it might help you

https://blog.netnerds.net/2012/03/solved-annoying-scrollbars-in-performancepoint-w-excel-services-pivotcharts-and-excel-web-access-web-parts/

Comment: Please avoid link only answer, since the link may break in the future making your answer useless....